# How can I load the latest model version from MLflow model registry?

Tags: mlflow, mlops

I can load a specific version of a model using the mlflow client:

```
import mlflow

model_version = 1

model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(
    model_uri=f"models:/c3760a15e6ac48f88ad7e5af940047d4/{model_version}"
)
```

But is there a way to load the latest model version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing, like load `latest`, but:

- You can specify the stage (`staging`, `production`) - see [docs](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/concepts.html#referencing-artifacts)
- You can find latest version using the [get_latest_versions](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.client.html#mlflow.client.MlflowClient.get_latest_versions) function - but it will also return latest per stage

So you need to define what `latest` means for you.

Comment: a bit of linkrot there

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get latest version

```
client = MlflowClient()
model_metadata = client.get_latest_versions(model_name, stages=["None"])
latest_model_version = model_metadata[0].version
latest_model_version
```

Comment: but how to get model_uri to load?